# Flex Bison constructed compiler prints correct results then gives syntax error

Tags: c++, parsing, compiler-construction, bison, flex-lexer

I am trying to construct a compiler. I built it,  but when I try it, it gives an error. Actually my bison created test.tab.cc file includes debugging tags, but I could not use them My test case is:

> ERROR.NEVER.A

My compiler  prints the right things ("**errrneverrraaabbbr**") but after that error method is somehow called and gives the error:

> "Error: syntax error at 1.1"

Does it mean first row first element, and what is wrong with it?

```
%skeleton "lalr1.cc"
%require  "3.0"
%debug 
%defines 
%define api.namespace {YK}
%define parser_class_name {YK_Parser}

%code requires{
   namespace YK {
      class YK_Driver;
      class YK_Scanner;
   }

// The following definitions is missing when %locations isn't used
# ifndef YY_NULLPTR
#  if defined __cplusplus && 201103L <= __cplusplus
#   define YY_NULLPTR nullptr
#  else
#   define YY_NULLPTR 0
#  endif
# endif

}

%parse-param { YK_Scanner  &scanner  }
%parse-param { YK_Driver  &driver  }

%code{
   #include <iostream>
   #include <cstdlib>
   #include <fstream>

   /* include for all driver functions */
   #include "yk_driver.hpp"

#undef yylex
#define yylex scanner.yylex
}

%define api.value.type variant
%define parse.assert
%token           DOT
%token               ERROR
%token               NEVER
%token               A
%token               B
%token               C
%token               BE
%token               AF
%start program

%%

program : rule ;

rule : vio DOT temp DOT event{std::cout<<"r";};

vio : ERROR{std::cout<<"errr";} 
                ;

temp :       NEVER{std::cout<<"neverrr";};

event : basic{std::cout<<"bbb";}
       |  basic DOT temp DOT basic{std::cout<<"c";}
      ;

temporal :  BE{std::cout<<"beeee";} 
          | AF{std::cout<<"affff";}
          ;

basic :      A{std::cout<<"aaa";} 
           | B{std::cout<<"bbb";}
           | C{std::cout<<"c";}
           ;
void test::test_Parser::error( const location_type &l, const std::string &err_message )
{
   std::cerr << std::endl << "Error: " << err_message << " at " << l << "\n";
}
```

---

```
%{
/* C++ string header, for string ops below */
#include <string>

/* Implementation of yyFlexScanner */ 
#include "yk_scanner.hpp"
#undef  YY_DECL
#define YY_DECL int YK::YK_Scanner::yylex( YK::YK_Parser::semantic_type * const lval, YK::YK_Parser::location_type *location )

/* typedef to make the returns for the tokens shorter */
using token = YK::YK_Parser::token;

/* define yyterminate as this instead of NULL */
#define yyterminate() return( token::END )

/* msvc2010 requires that we exclude this header file. */
#define YY_NO_UNISTD_H

/* update location on matching */
#define YY_USER_ACTION loc->step(); loc->columns(yyleng);

%}

%option debug
%option nodefault
%option yyclass="YK::YK_Scanner"
%option noyywrap
%option c++

%%
%{          /** Code executed at the beginning of yylex **/
            yylval = lval;
%}

[ \t\n]+        {} 
.       {return token::DOT;}
ERROR       {return token::ERROR;}
NEVER           {return token::NEVER;}
A           {return token::A;}
B           {return token::B;}
C           {return token::C;}
BE           {return token::BE;}
AF           {return token::AF;}
```

### PS. Inside yyerrlab label, my error string is generated. One of the following code is responsible for error.

```
if (yyn < 0 || yylast_ < yyn || yycheck_[yyn] != yyla.type_get ())
      goto yydefault;

    // Reduce or error.
    yyn = yytable_[yyn];
    if (yyn <= 0)
      {
        if (yy_table_value_is_error_ (yyn))
          goto yyerrlab;
        yyn = -yyn;
        goto yyreduce;
      }

    // Discard the token being shifted.
    yyempty = true;

    // Count tokens shifted since error; after three, turn off error status.
    if (yyerrstatus_)
      --yyerrstatus_;
```

---

```
/*-----------------------------------------------------------.
  | yydefault -- do the default action for the current state.  |
  `-----------------------------------------------------------*/
  yydefault:
    yyn = yydefact_[yystack_[0].state];
    if (yyn == 0)
      goto yyerrlab;
    goto yyreduce;
```

---

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <cstring>

#include "yk_driver.hpp"

int main( const int argc, const char **argv )
{
   /** check for the right # of arguments **/
   if( argc == 2 )
   {
      YK::YK_Driver driver;
      /** example for piping input from terminal, i.e., using cat **/ 
      if( std::strncmp( argv[ 1 ], "-o", 2 ) == 0 )
      {
         driver.parse( std::cin );
      }
      /** simple help menu **/
      else if( std::strncmp( argv[ 1 ], "-h", 2 ) == 0 )
      {
         std::cout << "use -o for pipe to std::cin\n";
         std::cout << "just give a filename to count from a file\n";
         std::cout << "use -h to get this menu\n";
         return( EXIT_SUCCESS );
      }
      /** example reading input from a file **/
      else
      {
         /** assume file, prod code, use stat to check **/
         driver.parse( argv[1] );
      }
      driver.print( std::cout ) << "\n";
   }
   else
   {
      /** exit with failure condition **/
      return ( EXIT_FAILURE );
   }
   return( EXIT_SUCCESS );
}
```

Comment: It might be useful to see your lexer code. The error could be caused by the tokens the lexer is passing, for example, what do you do with \r and \n etc?

Comment: @BrianTompsett-汤莱恩 i edited my post

Comment: yes: using a dot (.)  as the pattern is probably the fault, as it matches anything not just a dot. See http://flex.sourceforge.net/manual/The-period-isn_0027t-working-the-way-I-expected_002e.html . I was working on an answer, but did not have time yet...

Comment: I replaced . with & . And sitution did not change

Comment: Where is the code which calls the parset?

Comment: I added main cpp @rici

Comment: It is odd that you are not getting debugging output from the scanner. Are you sure your program is being built from the correct flex file? Maybe you need to do a clean build.

Comment: @rici do er need to define accepting state or something else

Comment: @setr: no. But as chris says, the input must actually end for the parse to succeed. Bison expects to see an EOF, which flex will return at the end of input.

Answer (score 2):

Most likely, this is caused by whatever is in your input after the `A` at the end of the line -- after parsing the `rule` (which is apparently being reduced, according to the ouput you show), it will be expecting an EOF to reduce the program and return.  If your lexer returns something other than an EOF, you'll get an error.  Perhaps a `\r` (carriage return), since your lexer does not appear to ignore that?

Comment: <<EOF>>  {yyterminate();} is enough or should i return to some token to parser like <<EOF>> { return token::EOF;}

Comment: @setr: flex automatically returns the correct token at EOF. Chris: i think this advice is misleading, unless there is something truly warped in tge C++ API.

Comment: If it is getting a syntax error as the OP describes, then the lexer is returning some token other than EOF after the A.  That token (whatever it is) is the problem.

Comment: /* define yyterminate as this instead of NULL */
#define yyterminate() return( token::END ) is responsible for this error. When I removed that line problem was fixed. After terminating it sends another token and crashes the compiler